# What kind of orange tree disease (or not) is this?

Tags: mildew, orange

There's a white discoloration on the leaves of my satsuma orange tree:

Photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aYcy.jpg

[image]

[image]

I'm uncertain if this is something that needs to be treated, or if it's just residue from a spray at the nursery. It came like this in the mail and does not appear to be spreading.

Comment: In places it looks like a surface coating, but in other places it looks like a discoloration of the leaf tissue under the surface. See if you can wipe it off or scrape it off with a fingernail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either pesticide spray residue or hard water stains. Either way just clean the leaves with a damp cloth.

Your confirmation will be that it does not show up on new growth.